# Get all similar values of key of bunch of (NSDictionary)s within an NSMuttableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMuttableArray having values like

```
(
{
    MedicineAlarmTime = "18:00:00";
    MedicineDateTime = "24/04/2014 16:00:09";
},
{
    MedicineAlarmTime = "18:00:00";
    MedicineDateTime = "24/04/2014 16:00:26";
},
{
    MedicineAlarmTime = "19:00:00";
    MedicineDateTime = "24/04/2014 16:00:26";
},
{
    MedicineAlarmTime = "19:00:00";
    MedicineDateTime = "24/04/2014 16:00:26";
}
)
```

Is it possible to retrieve arrays of similar "MedicineAlarmTime" like

```
array1 = (
{
    MedicineAlarmTime = "18:00:00";
    MedicineDateTime = "24/04/2014 16:00:09";
},
{
    MedicineAlarmTime = "18:00:00";
    MedicineDateTime = "24/04/2014 16:00:26";
}
)

array2 = (
{
    MedicineAlarmTime = "19:00:00"
    MedicineDateTime = "24/04/2014 16:00:09";
},
{
    MedicineAlarmTime = "19:00:00";
    MedicineDateTime = "24/04/2014 16:00:26";
}
)
```

Comment: Some clarity on "similar values or key" would be helpful.  Do you want these grouped per similar keys?  Or per similar values?  How similar do you mean?  Is 18:59:30 more similar to 19:00:30 or 18:00:30?  Is 18:15 similar enough to 18?  Or does it need its own group?

Comment: Sorry i made mistakes in writing. I have edited code. Check Now.

Comment: So if the value for the medicine alarm time key is identical, they should be sorted into the same array, else they should be in a different array?  By "similar", you meant "identical"?

Comment: As i explained arrays in question. If "MedicineAlarmTime" value is found "same" in more than one dictionaries, they are separated in different array.

Comment: You didn't actually explain that in the question, and the title says "similar".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *groupedAlarms = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary *alarm in originalArray) {
    NSString *alarmTime = [alarm objectForKey: MedicineAlarmTime];

    NSMutableArray *alarmGroup = [groupedAlarms objectForKey: MedicineAlarmTime]
    if (alarmGroup) {
        [alarmGroup addObject: alarm];
    } else {
        alarmGroup = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: alarm, nil];
        [groupedAlarms setValue:alarmGroup forKey:alarmTime];
    }
}
```

This creates an NSMutableDictionary, `groupedAlarms`.  The keys in `groupedAlarms` are the alarm times from the dictionaries in the original array--the actual alarm time value.  The values for each key are arrays.  The arrays contain the dictionaries of the original array--sorted based on the alarm time (which is used as the key to the array which contains them).

---

If you want the "alarmGroup" from the above example to be more general and not group exact matches only, you can use the same `forin` loop structure.  The checks to determine whether to put it in an existing group or create a new group become slightly more complex, but the important thing is, we still don't need to presort the array and then iterate through it a second time.

The only reason I can see for pre-sorting would be if you had a set number of groups you wanted, and a set number of objects in each group.  Then you can't really know what group to put each object in until the array has been sorted.

But here, we're trying to put objects in groups with similar object, so the algorithm is simple:

Grab an object.  See if it belongs in an existing group.  If not, create a new group for this object.  Move to the next object.

And for any downvoters... I can't really provide example code for a more complex example than the existing sample code in this answer unless the original question is made more clear.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem as originally posted. As originally posted, the alarm times were close together, but different.

Comment: The problem as originally posted was as vague as your answer. This answer solves the question currently posted after getting the OP to clarify the originally vague question, and is marked as the accepted answer. The downvoted is hardly called for.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You just have to write code for it.

First, you use the NSArray method sortedArrayUsingDescriptor: to get an array that is sorted by MedicineAlarmTime, so array elements that you might want together will actually be together. Then you iterate through the array, comparing the MedicineAlarmTime to check if two array elements are "similar" enough for you, and create arrays with those groups, using the NSArray method subArrayWithRange:

Comment: What a stupid comment. The poster wants _similar_ numbers, not _equal_ numbers. Times like "18:00:00" and "18:00:09" together. NSDictionary doesn't do that. If you are so clever, post some code that does this faster without sorting.

Comment: There is a faster way without sorting. I didn't down vote this answer. And you downvoted, assuring me mine was wrong despite OP accepting.

Comment: Don't fight guys. Be cool. Make me pardon. That was my fault. i made mistakes in representing my question.